# Stack is not handling data properly

Tags: java, string, parsing, stack

Ok, So i am working on a method that splits a numerical string into characters and pushes each character sequentially as an integer into two different stacks until it sees the operator skips it and then proceeds to push the rest of the characters as integers into the stacks. My stack keeps displaying numbers that are not being read. The text file being read looks like this:  28302830-293817302

```
public void pushToStack(String line) {

    boolean pushToFirstStack = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i))) {

            if(pushToFirstStack){
                System.out.print(Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i)));
                Stack1.push(Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i)));
            }else{
                System.out.print(Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i)));
                Stack2.push(Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i)));
            }

            pushToFirstStack = !pushToFirstStack;
        } else {
            //sets operator
            if(line.charAt(i) == add){
                return;
            }
            else{
                setAdd = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //displaying stacks debug
    Stack1.display();
    Stack2.display();
}
```

Comment: can you print the output you are getting?

Comment: Note: Why don't you divide your string in character array and then iterate over it? It will avoid using `line.charAt(i)` every time.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you did not provide example output makes it a little hard to answer, but I suspect that the line `pushToFirstStack = !pushToFirstStack;` should be in the `else` branch of the if.

Right now, you are building the first stack with the digits with odd indexes, and the second with the digits with even indexes, resulting in interleaved output.

Comment: That is the goal at the moment, its supposed to read first character, parse it to an int, push it to the first stack, then read the next character, parase it to an int, and push it to the second stack and keep going